# The use of the Past Simple after the Present Perfect

Tags: grammar, past-vs-present-perfect

Tell me please if I used the right tense in the following sentences.

> I have stumbled into the word that I cannot understand. I looked it up in a few dictionaries, but still have a hard time understanding it.

Would it be better to use the Present Perfect in the second sentence or the Past Simple is ok there?

Comment: Dmyrto:  either one. This is one of those "what-you-want-to-say" questions. There is no right or wrong here.

Comment: It's fine as written.  Lambie is correct and either is fine, but I prefer the present simple to indicate that it's a *current and ongoing problem* for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably say

> I stumbled **onto** a word that I cannot understand. I **have** looked it up in a few dictionaries, but still have a hard time understanding it.

So to directly answer your question, present perfect seems more natural to me.